# How to print an address in Xcode without a warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

The code below works OK, the address is printed, but gives a 'wrong type' warning. I'm quite new to Xcode, and expected an uncomplaining conversion of a pointer to an unsigned.

```
{NSLog(@"Released <%@> at %X, retain count now %lu", newEntry, newEntry, [newEntry retainCount]);}
```

Comment: retainCount is useless. Don't call it.

Comment: @bbum Well, umm, retainCount is actually interesting to follow, when you're learning.

Comment: Not really;  `retainCount` is misleading, at best.  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Comment: @bbum Yes, thanks, that debate is certainly part of the learning process.  Much obliged....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct format specifier for pointer address is %p:

```
NSLog(@"Released <%@> at %p, retain count now %lu", newEntry, newEntry, [newEntry retainCount]);
```

Answer (score 3):

%p is used for pointers.  Information can be found by looking in the String Programming Guide under Format Specifiers

Answer (score 1):

To print address of any instance variable you need to use %p.

```
NSLog(@"Address %p", newEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into this - its a more general solution
http://vgable.com/blog/tag/nslog/